# How to add hashtable to multidimensional array? Cannot assign values via member-access enumeration

Tags: arrays, powershell, syntax, hashtable, member-enumeration

I'm having trouble with adding hashtables to a multidimensional array. I coded the following:

```bsh
$Data = @{BIBs = @(
    @{$BIB = @{BIBName=$BIBName}, 
    @{Standort = $Standort}, 
    @{Bücher = @(
        @{BuchName = $BuchName; 
        Autor = $Autor
        })
    }}
)}
```

This code is functioning and creates an output, which I store in a JSON:

```json
{
    "BIBs": [
        {
            "BIB1": [
                {
                    "BIBName": "123"
                },
                {
                    "Standort": "123"
                },
                {
                    "Bücher": [
                        {
                            "Autor": "123",
                            "BuchName": "123"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "BIB2": [
                {
                    "BIBname": "345"
                },
                {
                    "Standort": "345"
                },
                {
                    "Bücher": [
                        {
                            "Autor": "345",
                            "Buchname": "345"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have extra code which adds another hashtable to array "BIBs" as you can see.

```bsh
$jsonfile = "C:\Skripte\bibV2-1000.json"
$Data = Get-Content $jsonfile | ConvertFrom-Json
$Data.BIBs += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
    $BIB = @{BIBname=$BIBName}, @{Standort=$Standort},
           @{Bücher = @(@{Buchname=$BuchName;Autor=$Autor})}
}
```

When the output is like above, I'm not able to add another hashtable to "Bücher". I checked the type of "Bücher" with

```bsh
$data.BIBs.BIB1.Bücher.GetType()
```

and it's actually an array:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name     BaseType
-------- -------- ----     --------
True     True     Object[] System.Array
```

I tried

```bsh
$Data.BIBs.BIB1.Bücher += @{Person="Max";Alter="35"}
```

to add a new hashtable, like I did with "BIB2", but I am getting the error:

```
The property 'Bücher' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property
exists and can be set.
At line:5 char:1
+ $data.BIBs.BIB1.Bücher += @{Motor="asdf";pers="345"}
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

Do you know how I add `@{Person="Max";Alter="35"}` to "Bücher"?

Comment: The assignment is ambiguous - should it write to `$Data.BIBs[0].BIB1[0].Bücher`? That certainly doesn't exist

Comment: What is the result of `$data.BIBs.GetType()` and `$data.BIBs.BIB1.GetType()`?

Comment: The result of both is the same like above: System.Array

Comment: Reading and writing ain't the same thing. You're relying on property enumeration when reading

Comment: Okay, that means I can't write my hashtable to "Bücher" like I wanted to? How can I do it instead? Why is it possible to write e.g. "BIB2" to "BIBs", I rely on one property aswell, or is it only a problem relying on multiple properties?

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

*Setting* a key / property value via *member-access enumeration* is not supported (see below).

Instead, you **must obtain the specific object whose `.Bücher` property you want to modify explicitly**:

```bash
($Data.BIBs.BIB1 | ? Bücher).Bücher += @{ BuchName='neues Buch'; Autor='Johann Doe' }
```

Note: This assumes that:

- only *one* element of array `$Data.BIBs.BIB1` has a `.Bücher` property (key)
- that, if the property / key does exist, it is *nonempty* and therefore is "truthy" in a Boolean context, such as the expression passed to `?` (`Where-Object`); like member-access enumeration, this simplified `Where-Object` syntax - `? Bücher` instead of `? { $_.Bücher }` - is a PSv3+ feature, called [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax).

---

[Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) has provided the crucial pointer in comments on the question:

**PowerShell has an intentional asymmetry with respect to dot notation across *collection-valued* properties for *getting* values vs. *setting* values.**

- **On *getting*, PSv3+ applies [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375)**, which, in a nutshell, allows you to access a property on a *collection* and implicitly get that property's value from *each element IN that collection*, with the results getting collected in an *array*.
- **On *setting*, member-access enumeration is *not* applied**; the rationale is that the risk of unintentional modification of data is too high - see [GitHub issue #5271](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5271) and in particular [this comment](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5271#issuecomment-340285892) by a core member of the PS team.

The unfortunate aspect is that **the current error message doesn't tell you that**.
It stems from the fact that when attempting to *set* a property at the collection level, the property is looked for only *directly on the collection* (instead of on its elements), where it (usually) doesn't exist.

Let's take a look at a simplified example:

```bash
$data = @{ # a hashtable
  a = ( # array of hashtables
    @{ b1 = 'b1' },
    @{ b2 = 'b2' },
    @{ b3 = 
      @{ b31 = 'b31' }, @{ b32 = 'b32' } # array of hashtables
    }
  )
}
```

**On *getting***, everything **works fine**:

```bash
PS> $data.a.b3

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
b31                            b31                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
b32                            b32
```

Even though `$data.a` is an `[object[]]` array, an object (hashtable) with property `.b3` was found among its *elements*, and that object's `.b3` value is output.
This is member-access enumeration in action (although the more typical uses is case for the property to exist on *all* elements of the array and for the individual values to be collected in an `[object[]]` array).

**On *setting***, PowerShell forgoes member-access enumeration and therefore **unsuccessfully looks for a `.b3` property *only* directly on the `[object[]]` instance that is `$data.a`** and, of course, arrays have no `.b3` property:

```bash
PS> $data.a.b3 += @{ b33 = 'b33' }  # Try to add an element; !! FAILS

The property 'b3' cannot be found on this object. 
Verify that the property exists and can be set.
...
```