# How to get index of hashtable in array?

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable

I'm having a little trouble finding the index of a hashtable in an array. I create a JSON with this code:

```
$start = {
Clear-Host
$BIB = Read-Host 'Bibliothek'
$BIBName = Read-Host 'Bibliothek Name'
$Standort = Read-Host 'Bibliothek Standort'
$Autor = Read-Host 'Buchautor'
$BuchName = Read-Host 'Buchname'

$jsonfile = "C:\Skripte\bibV2-1000.xml"
if(![System.IO.File]::Exists($jsonfile)){
    $Data = @{BIBs = @(
        @{$BIB = @{BIBName=$BIBName}, 
        @{Standort = $Standort}, 
        @{Bücher = @(
            @{BuchName = $BuchName; 
            Autor = $Autor})
        }}
    )}
    ConvertTo-Json -Depth 50 -InputObject $Data | Add-Content $jsonfile
    .$continue
} else {
        $jsonfile = "C:\Skripte\bibV2-1000.json"
        $Data = Get-Content $jsonfile | ConvertFrom-Json
        $Data.BIBs += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{$BIB = 
               @{BIBname=$BIBName},
               @{Standort=$Standort},
               @{Bücher = @(@{
                    Buchname=$BuchName;
                    Autor=$Autor})
               }
        }
        ConvertTo-Json -Depth 50 -InputObject $Data | Out-File $jsonfile}
        .$continue
}


$continue = {
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Was wollen Sie machen?"
Write-Host "(1) Eine weitere Bibliothek hinzufügen"
Write-Host "(2) Einer Bibliothek neue Bücher hinzufügen"
Write-Host "(E) Script beenden"

    If (($read = Read-Host ) -eq "1") {
    &$start} else {
            if (($read) -eq "2") {
                . C:\Skripte\büc.ps1 } else {
                    if (($read) -eq "E") {
                        exit} else {
                            Write-Host "+++ FALSCHE EINGABE! Bitte wählen Sie (1) oder (2) für die entsprechende Aktion +++"
                            .$continue
                        }
                }
    }
}
&$start
```

The output is as follows:

```
{
    "BIBs": [{
        "BIB1": [{
            "BIBName": "123"
        },
            {
                "Standort": "123"
            },
            {
                "Bücher": [{
                    "Autor": "123",
                    "BuchName": "123"
                }]
            }
        ]
    },
        {
            "BIB2": [{
                "BIBname": "345"
            },
                {
                    "Standort": "345"
                },
                {
                    "Bücher": [{
                        "Autor": "345",
                        "Buchname": "345"
                    }]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to find out the index of "BIB1". I already tried the IndexOf()-Method which should create the output "0" but it gives me "-1" instead, because it can't find the value. How can I get the index of "BIB1"?

Comment: can you show the objects you are working with?
this just looks like a json object

Comment: Please edit your question with this information. Reading code in comments sucks...

Comment: So. One thing about ConvertTo-Json is that it doesn't make a "Json Object". It just creates a Json formatted string. If you want a structured data object that you can easily manipulate and poke around in I would suggest either leaving it as a hash of arrays and hashes as you had it before you converted it or converting it to XML.

Comment: I already tried it without converting it to json, but the output of IndexOf() is still "-1"

Comment: Already tried what? Already tried how? What code did you try with?

Comment: The code that you have provided will not run since you did not provide all the code. Please create a [Minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your situation.

Comment: I filled $Data with values but didn't convert it to json. After that I tried `$Data.BIBs.IndexOf('BIB1') to get the index of the first value "BIB1". The output was still "-1" instead of  "0", it somehow can't find the value "BIB1".

Comment: $Data.BIBs is an array of ***HashTables*** you are asking it to tell you the location of a ***String***. That string literally does not exist as a member of that array. It is a key in a hashtable that is a member of that array.

Comment: That's the problem, how can I adress the hashtable to get its index in the array of $Data.BIBs?

Comment: Let's back up a little. Why are you using this data structure? Are you locked into doing it this way because you are required to produce that specific Json?

Comment: Exactly, I can't alter the structure as it is needed this way. The structure is going to be used for an onboarding-process for customers in a project that I'm working on. The idea behind my question is, that I want to add another value to e.g. **"BIB1"** or even **"Bücher"**. Therefor I already coded a snippet for adding a value to it. But the code is only functioning with the index of the array. So I want to find out the index of "BIB1" dynamically instead of hardcoding it, because hardcoding the index is not a proper way of doing that task. `$Data.BIBs[0].BIB1[2].Bücher += @{A="B";C="F"}`

Comment: Well, I would say that if you are working on the project maybe you should work on a less complicated data structure. Without that as an option though, give me a minute to mock up an actual [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that I can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Judging by your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49297050/45375), you're attempting to get the *index* of a specific object so you can *access it* via its containing array. However, you can do this more directly: `$objOfInterest = $Data.BIBs | ? BIB1` - see my [answer to your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49410110/45375) for details.</sup>

You need to iterate over the array elements of `$Data.BIBs`, which - on reading your serialized-to-a-file-as-JSON hashtables back in with `ConvertFrom-Json` - are *custom objects* (as Ansgar correctly points out; they are instances of `[System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]`), and check each for the presence of *property* `'BIB1'`:

- (In a hashtable, you'd check for the presence of *key* `'BIB1'` with `.ContainsKey('BIB1')`)
- To test the existence of an object *property*, you need *reflection*, which is most easily - but somewhat obscurely - achieved via the hidden `.PSObject` property, as demonstrated in [Ansgar Wiechers' more elegant solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49386677/45375).

However, given that the properties of interest have nonempty values, we can *infer* from the presence of a nonempty value that a given property exists, using implicit Boolean (logic): `$obj.'BIB1'` by default returns `$null` if there is no `BIB1` property, which is "falsy" in a Boolean context such as an `if` conditional; conversely, any nonempty value is "truthy":

```
$propName = 'BIB1'
$i = $ndx = -1
foreach ($obj in $Data.BIBs) {
  ++$i
  if ($obj.$propName) { $ndx = $i; break}
}
$ndx  # $ndx now contains the index of the target object or -1 if there was no match
```

Answer (score 2):

`$Date.BIBs` is an array of custom objects, not hashtables (since you wrote your original data to a JSON file and then converted that back), so you need something like this:

```
$arr = $Data.BIBs | ForEach-Object { $_.PSObject.Properties.Name }
$arr.IndexOf('BIB1')  # returns 0
$arr.IndexOf('BIB2')  # returns 1
```