# PowerShell JSON set value

Tags: json, powershell

Folks,
I do run in PowerShell some ReST api call and do get back a

```
$response

page                                                content
----                                                -------
@{size=20; number=0; totalPages=1; totalElements=1} {@{id=ZGR2ZS0yLnZsYWIubG9j…
```

When I convert to JSON

PS C:\Users\Administrator\Documents> $response | ConvertTo-Json

```
{
  "page": {
    "size": 20,
    "number": 0,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "totalElements": 1
  },
  "content": [
    {
      "id": "ZGR2ZS0yLnZsYWIubG9jYWw6MzAwOTpob3N0",
      "host": "ddve-2.vlab.local",
      "port": "3009",
      "notValidBefore": "Fri Mar 29 21:32:19 PDT 2019",
      "notValidAfter": "Sat Mar 29 04:32:19 PDT 2025",
      "fingerprint": "E1BB40B0284595297071177FE02BC9C76E85CD66",
      "subjectName": "CN=ddve-2.vlab.local, O=Valued DataDomain customer, OU=Hos
t Certificate, ST=CA, C=US",
      "issuerName": "CN=ddve-2.vlab.local, OU=Root CA, O=Valued Datadomain Custo
mer, L=Santa Clara, ST=CA, C=US",
      "state": "ACCEPTED",
      "type": "HOST"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
an idividual value can be seen

PS C:\Users\Administrator\Documents> $response.content.state
ACCEPTED
```

But setting a new value fails

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Documents> $response.content.state = 123
InvalidOperation: The property 'state' cannot be found on this object. Verify th
at the property exists and can be set.
```

Comment: try using `.GetType()` on the various levels/properties of your object. i suspect that you have a hashtable in there somewhere and will need to carefully look at how to address the key/value pairs.

Comment: Content is an array with a single object: `$response.content[0].state = 123`

Answer (score 3):

Because **your `content` property is a (single-element) *array*** (as evidenced by its value being enclosed in `[ ... ]` in the JSON representation), you **must use an *index* to specify which element's `.state` property to *set*:**

```sh
$response.content[0].state = 123
```

Note that **an index is not required for *getting* the value** (that is, `$response.content.state` works and returns `"ACCEPTED"`, as you state), because PowerShell then applies [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375), which means that it enumerates the `state` property values of all elements of the array (which with a single-element array returns just the single element's value, and with a multiple-element array returns an *array* of values).

**On *setting* a property value, member-access enumeration is by design *not* supported**, although the error message could certainly be more helpful - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49410110/45375).

Answer (score -1):

Your object is a PSCustomObject and the value you're trying to change is a NoteProperty on that object, you can use `Add-Member` with the `-Force` switch to overwrite it.

```
$Response = @"
{
  "page": {
    "size": 20,
    "number": 0,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "totalElements": 1
  },
  "content": [
    {
      "id": "ZGR2ZS0yLnZsYWIubG9jYWw6MzAwOTpob3N0",
      "host": "ddve-2.vlab.local",
      "port": "3009",
      "notValidBefore": "Fri Mar 29 21:32:19 PDT 2019",
      "notValidAfter": "Sat Mar 29 04:32:19 PDT 2025",
      "fingerprint": "E1BB40B0284595297071177FE02BC9C76E85CD66",
      "subjectName": "CN=ddve-2.vlab.local, O=Valued DataDomain customer, OU=Hos
t Certificate, ST=CA, C=US",
      "issuerName": "CN=ddve-2.vlab.local, OU=Root CA, O=Valued Datadomain Custo
mer, L=Santa Clara, ST=CA, C=US",
      "state": "ACCEPTED",
      "type": "HOST"
    }
  ]
}
"@ | ConvertFrom-Json

$Response.Content.State
$Response.Content | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name State -Value 123 -Force
$Response.Content.State
```

Output

```
ACCEPTED
123
```

Comment: The OP's only problem is that `.content` is an _array_  and that the array's (only) _element_ is the object that has the `.state` property of interest. It can be set directly, as long as the array element is explicitly targeted _by index_ (`$response.content[0].state = ...`). Your approach happens to work, because use of the pipeline _enumerates_ the array, but the use of  an extra pipeline with `Add-Member`  is both unnecessary and slow.