# "The property cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists." Property definitely exists

Tags: json, powershell, psobject

I can't figure out why I am not able to change these variables. If I type them into the console in debug mode, then it prints the values. It is also strange how I am able to change the allowedRequestors variable on line 24, but not any of the others. Does anyone know why this is happening to the other variables?

```
$FilePath = "C:\Users\Desktop\TestScripts\testBulkAP.csv"

$headers = & $PSScriptRoot\GetToken.ps1

## preparing create Catalog data
$accesspacakgeRequest = '{"displayName":"","description":"sddsds","isHidden":false,"catalogId":"","accessPackageResourceRoleScopes":[],"accessPackageAssignmentPolicies":[{"displayName":"Initial Policy","description":"Initial Policy","durationInDays":365,"expirationDateTime":null,"canExtend":false,"requestApprovalSettings":null,"accessReviewSettings":null,"notificationSettings":null,"additionalInfo":null,"isDenyPolicy":false,"id":"","activeAssignmentCount":0,"accessPackageId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","accessPackageCatalog":null,"createdDateTime":null,"modifiedDateTime":null,"createdBy":"","modifiedBy":"","countOfUsersIncludedInPolicy":null,"requestorSettings":{"acceptRequests":true,"scopeType":"NoSubjects","allowedRequestors":[],"isOnBehalfAllowed":false},"questions":[]}]}'
$emlRequestUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identityGovernance/entitlementManagement/accessPackages"
$accesspacakgeRequestObject = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $accesspacakgeRequest

$Content = Import-Csv $FilePath

foreach($assignmentData in $Content) {
    $accesspacakgeRequestObject.catalogId = $assignmentData.catalogId
    $accesspacakgeRequestObject.displayName = $assignmentData.displayName
    $accesspacakgeRequestObject.description = $assignmentData.description
    $accesspacakgeRequestObject.accessPackageAssignmentPolicies.requestorSettings.scopeType = $assignmentData.scope 

    if ($assignmentData.scope -eq "SpecificDirectorySubjects") {
    $accesspacakgeRequestObject.accessPackageAssignmentPolicies.requestorSettings.allowedRequestors += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{'@odata.type' = '#microsoft.graph.groupMembers'; 'id' = $assignmentData.groupId; 'description' = $assignmentData.groupName; 'isBackup' = 'false'}
    }

    $numApprovalStages = [int]$assignmentData.approvalStages

    if ($numApprovalStages -gt 0) {
    $accesspacakgeRequestObject.accessPackageAssignmentPolicies.requestApprovalSettings += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{'approvalMode' = 'Serial'; 'isApprovalRequired' = 'true'; 'isApprovalRequiredForExtension' = 'false'; 'isRequestorJustificationRequired' = 'false'; 'approvalStages' = @()}

    for ($i=1;$i -le [int]$assignmentData.approvalStages; $i++)
    {
        $accesspacakgeRequestObject.accessPackageAssignmentPolicies.requestApprovalSettings.approvalStages += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{'approvalStageTimeOutInDays' = '14'; 'primaryApprovers' = @(); escalationApprovers = @();'isEscalationEnabled' = 'false'; 'escalationTimeInMinutes' = '0'; 'isApproverJustificationRequired' = 'true'}
        $accesspacakgeRequestObject.accessPackageAssignmentPolicies.requestApprovalSettings.approvalStages.primaryApprovers += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{'@odata.type' = '#microsoft.graph.singleUser'; "displayName" = ''; 'objectId' = Get-Variable -Name "assignmentData.approver$1" -ValueOnly; 'isBackup' = 'false'}
        
    }

    }
    
    
    
    $requestbody = $accesspacakgeRequestObject | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod $emlRequestUrl -Headers $headers -Method Post -Body $requestbody -UseBasicParsing -ErrorAction Continue
}
```

The error message is:

```
The property 'requestApprovalSettings' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At C:\Users\Desktop\TestScripts\AddAccessPackageAndPolicyWITHAPPROVER.ps1:30 char:5
+     $accesspacakgeRequestObject.accessPackageAssignmentPolicies.reque ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
 
The property 'approvalStages' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At C:\Users\Desktop\TestScripts\AddAccessPackageAndPolicyWITHAPPROVER.ps1:34 char:9
+         $accesspacakgeRequestObject.accessPackageAssignmentPolicies.r ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
 
Get-Variable : Cannot find a variable with the name 'assignmentData.approver1'.
At C:\Users\Desktop\TestScripts\AddAccessPackageAndPolicyWITHAPPROVER.ps1:35 char:250
+ ... objectId' = Get-Variable -Name "assignmentData.approver$i" -ValueOnly ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (assignmentData.approver1:String) [Get-Variable], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetVariableCommand
 
The property 'primaryApprovers' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At C:\Users\Desktop\TestScripts\AddAccessPackageAndPolicyWITHAPPROVER.ps1:35 char:250
+ ... objectId' = Get-Variable -Name "assignmentData.approver$i" -ValueOnly ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `.accessPackageAssignmentPolicies` property contains an *array* (`[...]`-enclosed in the JSON input).

Even though that array happens to contain only *one* element, you still need to access it *by index* in order to *set* its (only) element's properties; e.g.:

```sh
# Note the `[0]`
$accesspacakgeRequestObject.accessPackageAssignmentPolicies[0].requestorSettings.scopeType = $assignmentData.scope
```

Note that *getting* properties does *not* strictly require this index access, because of a feature called [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375).

This perhaps surprising asymmetry - *requiring* indexed access on *setting* - is [by design](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5271#issuecomment-340285892), however - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49410110/45375) for more information.