# Powershell: The property 'WorkingDirectory' cannot be found on this object (WIN10 - 18363) but exist

Tags: windows, powershell, properties

Hy, i try to use powershell to automate some scheduling tasks
Should start a cmd.exe in a specific directory.

Unfortunately it returns an error on a specific property

Property: TaskName.Actions.WorkingDirectory

```
# Testprog for Scheduler working directory setup
cls
$TaskName = "TestTask"

# Helpers for Task creation comment out when task exist
UnRegister-ScheduledTask -TaskName $TaskName  

$Description = " Test Powershell Task creation"
$Trigger= New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 02:00pm  
$Action= New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute cmd.exe -Argument $StartString 

$ProgPath = """e:\Temp\Software\7zip\7za.exe"""
$Param =  " a -t7z -bd -ssw -wE:\Temp"
$Archive = " ""E:\Temp\LocalArch\TestArch.7z"""
$SourcePath = " ""E:\Logs\"" "
$User= "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"

$StartString = "/c " + $ProgPath + $Param + $Archive + $SourcePath

Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $TaskName -Trigger $Trigger -User $User -Action $Action -RunLevel Highest –Force -Description $Description 

#>


$Task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName $TaskName  # Read Scheduler Task to Object

$Task.Actions.WorkingDirectory   # Retrieve no error
# E:\WrittenViaGUI  # Test return value written via schduler GUI

$Task.Actions.WorkingDirectory = "E:\Temp\"  #New working dir
```

Error: The property 'WorkingDirectory' cannot be found on this object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name of the property suggests, `$Task.Actions` contains a *collection* of values (even if in a given situation that collection contains just *one* element).

PowerShell's [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) feature allows you to use property access (`.WorkingDirectory`) on a collection to *get* the property values of its *elements* - that is why `$Task.Actions.WorkingDirectory` succeeded - but *not* also to *set* property values - that is why `$Task.Actions.WorkingDirectory = ...` failed.

You solution options are:

- If you know that `.Actions` contains only *one* action, simply use `[0]` to access the one and only element:

  ```sh
  $Task.Actions[0].WorkingDirectory = 'E:\Temp\'
  ```
- If `.Actions` contains *multiple* actions, and you want to set *all* their working directories to the *same value*:

  ```sh
  $Task.Actions.ForEach('WorkingDirectory', 'E:\Temp\')

  # Slower alternatives
  $Task.Actions.ForEach({ $_.WorkingDirectory = 'E:\Temp\' })
  $Task.Actions | ForEach-Object { $_.WorkingDirectory = 'E:\Temp\' }
  ```

For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49410110/45375).

Comment: $Task.Actions[0].WorkingDirectory = 'E:\Temp\' works for me, Thanks