# Set property value on object loaded from json containing comments

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-7.0

When loading an object from a json file one can normally set the value on properties and write the file back out like so:

```
$manifest = (gc $manifestPath) | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable
$manifest.name = "$($manifest.name)-sxs"
$manifest | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | Out-File $manifestPath -Encoding utf8NoBOM
```

But if the source json file contains comments, the object's properties can't be set:

```
// *******************************************************
// GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT DIRECTLY
// *******************************************************
{
  "name": "PublishBuildArtifacts"
}
```

Running the code above throws an error:

```
$manifest

id                 : 1D341BB0-2106-458C-8422-D00BCEA6512A
name               : PublishBuildArtifacts
friendlyName       : ms-resource:loc.friendlyName
description        : ms-resource:loc.description
category           : Build
visibility         : {Build}
author             : Microsoft Corporation
version            : @{Major=0; Minor=1; Patch=71}
demands            : {}
inputs             : {@{name=CopyRoot; type=filePath; label=ms-resource:loc.input.label.CopyRoot; defaultValue=;
                     required=False; helpMarkDown=Root folder to apply copy patterns to.  Empty is the root of the
                     repo.}, @{name=Contents; type=multiLine; label=ms-resource:loc.input.label.Contents;
                     defaultValue=; required=True; helpMarkDown=File or folder paths to include as part of the
                     artifact.}, @{name=ArtifactName; type=string; label=ms-resource:loc.input.label.ArtifactName;
                     defaultValue=; required=True; helpMarkDown=The name of the artifact to create.},
                     @{name=ArtifactType; type=pickList; label=ms-resource:loc.input.label.ArtifactType;
                     defaultValue=; required=True; helpMarkDown=The name of the artifact to create.; options=}…}
instanceNameFormat : Publish Artifact: $(ArtifactName)
execution          : @{PowerShell=; Node=}

$manifest.name
PublishBuildArtifacts

$manifest.name = "sxs"
InvalidOperation: The property 'name' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
```

When I strip the comments, I can overwrite the property.

Is there a way I can coax PowerShell to ignore the comments while loading the json file/convert the object and generate a writable object?

Comment: Use the `-Raw` switch on `Get-Content` not sure if this is intended but it works that way. On the other hand, it's worth noting that the Json will not be compatible with Windows PowerShell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is intended, but seems like `ConvertFrom-Json` is treating the comments on the Json as `$null` when converting it to an object. **This only happens if it's receiving an `object[]` from pipeline, with a *string* or *multi-line string* it works fine**.

A simple way to demonstrate this using the exact same Json posted in the question:

```
$contentAsArray = Get-Content test.json | Where-Object {
    -not $_.StartsWith('/')
} | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable

$contentAsArray['name'] = 'hello' # works
```

Here you can see the differences and the workaround, it is definitely recommended to use `-Raw` on `Get-Content` so you're passing a *multi-line string* to `ConvertFrom-Json`:

```
$contentAsString = Get-Content test.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable
$contentAsArray = Get-Content test.json | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable

$contentAsString.PSObject, $contentAsArray.PSObject | Select-Object TypeNames, BaseObject

TypeNames                                      BaseObject
---------                                      ----------
{System.Collections.Hashtable, System.Object}  {name}
{System.Object[], System.Array, System.Object} {$null, System.Collections.Hashtable}


$contentAsArray['name']      # null
$null -eq $contentAsArray[0] # True
$contentAsArray[1]['name']   # PublishBuildArtifacts
$contentAsArray[1]['name'] = 'hello'
$contentAsArray[1]['name']   # hello
```

Comment: Crazy stuff. Luckily `-Raw` did the trick. PowerShell keeps tripping my up with magic conversions and weird behavior. Usually when something magically turns into an array. I wish it would stop ding that.

Comment: @jessehouwing _"magic conversions and weird behavior"_ sounds a lot like PowerShell  still one grows to love it lol. Happy it worked out for you.

Answer (score 2):

[Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71026007/45375) shows an effective solution and analyzes the symptom. Let me complement it with some **background information**.

**tl;dr**

- You're seeing **a variation of a *known bug***, still present as of PowerShell 7.2.1, where a blank line or a single-line comment as the *first* input object unexpectedly causes `$null` to be emitted (first) - see [GitHub issue #12229](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12229).
- **Using `-Raw` with [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) isn't just a *workaround*, it is the *right - and faster - thing to do*** when piping a file containing JSON to be parsed as whole to [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json)

---

For ***multiple* input objects (strings)**, **`ConverFrom-Json` has a(n unfortunate) *heuristic* built in** that **tries to *infer*** whether the multiple strings represent either **(a)** the lines of a single JSON document or **(b)** separate, individual JSON documents, each on its own line, as follows:

- If the *first* input string is valid JSON *by itself*, (b) is assumed, and an object representing the parsed JSON (`[pscustomobject]` or , with `-AsHashtable`, `[hastable]`, or an array of either) is output *for each input string*.
- Otherwise, (a) is assumed and all input strings are *collected first*, in a multi-line string, which is *then* parsed.

The aforementioned bug is that if the first string is an empty/blank line or a single-line comment<sup>[1]</sup> (applies to both `// ...` comments, which are *invariably* single-line, and `/* ... */` if they *happen to be* single-line), (b) is (justifiably) assumed, *but an extraneous `$null`* is emitted before the remaining (non-blank, non-comment) lines are parsed and their object representation(s) are output.

As a result an *array* is invariably returned, whose first element is `$null` - which isn't obvious, but results in subtle changes in behavior, as you've experienced:

Notably, attempting to set a *property* on what is presumed to be a *single* object then fails, because the fact that an *array* is being accessed makes the property access an instance of [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) - implicitly applying property access to all *elements* of a collection rather than the collection itself - which only works for *getting* property values - and fails obscurely when *setting* is attempted - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49410110/45375) for details.

A simplified example:

```bash
# Sample output hashtable parsed from JSON
$manifest = @{ name = 'foo' }

# This is what you (justifiably) THOUGHT you were doing.
$manifest.name = 'bar' # OK

# Due to the bug, this is what you actually attempted.
($null, $manifest).name = 'bar' # !! FAILS - member-access enumeration doesn't support setting.
```

As noted above, the resulting error message - `The property 'name' cannot be found on this object. ...` - is unhelpful, as it doesn't indicate the true cause of the problem.

Improving it would be tricky, however, as the user's intent is inherently ambiguous: the property name may EITHER be a situationally unsuccessful attempt to reference a nonexistent property *of the collection itself* OR, as in this case, a fundamentally unsupported attempt at setting properties *via member-access enumeration*.

Conceivably, the following would help if the target object is a collection (enumerable) from PowerShell's perspective: `The property 'name' cannot be found on this collection, and setting a collection's elements' properties by member-access enumeration isn't supported.`

---

<sup>[1] Note that comments in JSON are supported in *PowerShell (Core) v6+* only.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed helpful. What also would have helped is when PowerShell would clearly dump the array to the console instead of the json object. As you can see dumping `$manifest`akes no mention of this being an array or the fest element being null. Though it may be that that's why it renders a blank line. Even in the debugger under Vscode, this isn't obvious.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @jessehouwing. The problem with detecting this is that PowerShell's output-formatting system generally doesn't visualize `$null` - neither by itself, nor as part of arrays; e.g.,  `$null, 'foo'` renders the same as `'foo'`. Sadly, `Measure-Object` too ignores `$null`s (see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10905). Your best (obscure) bet is to use `Format-Custom -InputObject ($null, 'foo')` (note: use `-InputObject`, not pipeline input), which renders a `$null` as an empty line. (And, of course, `$var.GetType()` will tell you whether something is an array).

Comment: Would setting the type of the variable have surfaced the issue?

Comment: @jessehouwing, yes, type-constraining the variable would have surfaced an error: `[hashtable] $manifest = ...` without `-Raw` reports `Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Collections.Hashtable".`

Comment: @jessehouwing, however, it wouldn't help if you omitted `-AsHashTable` and type-constrained with `[pscustomobject]`, because casting an array to `[pscustomobject]` simply wraps the whole array in a (mostly) invisible `[psobject]`  wrapper (`[psobject]` is the same as `[pscustomobject]`, sadly, and use of `[pscustomobject]` outside of a custom-object _literal_ is virtually pointless).