# Powershell iterate System.Object

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface, openshift

I am using OpenShift CLI in a PowerShell Script,

I have a variable $ProjectList with Data. Not sure of its datatype, but doing $ProjectsList.GetType() gives me below

```text
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Looking for a way to Get Name field whose status is running

```text
NAME                                             READY   STATUS             AGE
Service One                                     0/1     Completed            13d
Service Two                                     0/1     Running              13d
Service 3                                       0/1     Running              13d
Service 4                                       0/1     Completed            13d
```

`$ProjectList.Length` give me the value 5.

I am looking for a way to get the Name whole status is Running. Tried below code but it does not work.

```sh
$ProjectsList = c:\TEMP\oc.exe get pods
$FilteredList = $ProjectList.Where{ $_.STATUS -eq 'Running' }

write-host $FilteredList //This shows empty
```

Can you help me with some pseudo code.

Comment: `==` in PowerShell would be `-eq` :)

Comment: "I have a variable $ProjectList with Data. Not sure of its datatype" - where did you obtain the data? How did it make its way into `$ProjectList`? :)

Comment: Santi's comment should fix your problem. Also, you can use `Where-Object`, or it's partner the `.Where({})` operator to filter for that info instead of a loop: `$ProjectList.Where{ $_.Status -eq 'Running' }`. Here's the same using the cmdlet instead: `$ProjectList | Where "Status" -eq "Running"`.

Comment: I am using OpenShift OC CLI to get some data from OpenShift clusters.  The above Where clause does not work. Edited the code to show the OC command that I use to get data

Comment: @RPK You have not addressed the incorrect usage of `==` in your code above. The correct operator for comparing equality is `-eq`.

Comment: I have removed the If condition and also forloop, the where condition does not return any filtered data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query does not work because the CLI outputs table format by default. So your `$ProjectList` just contains the formatted text output as an array of strings, which PowerShell does not understand.

According to the [docs](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.8/cli_reference/openshift_cli/developer-cli-commands.html#oc-get), the CLI is able to output JSON format, by passing argument `-o json`. This can easily be parsed into actual objects by using PowerShell's [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) cmdlet:

```sh
$ProjectsList = c:\TEMP\oc.exe get pods -o json | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json

$FilteredList = $ProjectList.Where{ $_.STATUS -eq 'Running' }
```

The [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) call is there because `ConvertFrom-Json` works best (most predictably<sup>1</sup>) when given a single input string. When redirecting the output of a native process, you would normally get each line one-by-one, as a separate string. Using `Out-String` makes sure that the next command in the pipeline receives the output as a single multiline string instead.

<sup>1) See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71053689/7571258) for pitfalls when passing multiple strings to `ConvertFrom-Json`.</sup>