# Convert JSON to a PowerShell Object, then, replace that Object with a new Object and convert back to JSON

Tags: powershell

### Background

I have some JSON for a Packer build like so:

```json
{
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "azure-arm"
    }
  ],
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "scripts": [
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/docker-compose.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/docker-moby.sh"
      ],
      "environment_vars": [
        "HELPER_SCRIPTS\u003d{{user `helper_script_folder`}}",
        "INSTALLER_SCRIPT_FOLDER\u003d{{user `installer_script_folder`}}",
        "DOCKERHUB_LOGIN\u003d{{user `dockerhub_login`}}",
        "DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD\u003d{{user `dockerhub_password`}}"
      ],
      "execute_command": "sudo sh -c \u0027{{ .Vars }} {{ .Path }}\u0027"
    },
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "scripts": [
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/azcopy.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/azure-cli.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/azure-devops-cli.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/basic.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/bicep.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/aliyun-cli.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/apache.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/aws.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/clang.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/swift.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/cmake.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/codeql-bundle.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/containers.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/dotnetcore-sdk.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/erlang.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/firefox.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/gcc.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/gfortran.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/git.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/github-cli.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/google-chrome.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/google-cloud-sdk.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/haskell.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/heroku.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/hhvm.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/java-tools.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/kubernetes-tools.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/oc.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/leiningen.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/miniconda.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/mono.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/kotlin.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/mysql.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/mssql-cmd-tools.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/sqlpackage.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/nginx.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/nvm.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/nodejs.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/bazel.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/oras-cli.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/phantomjs.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/php.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/postgresql.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/pulumi.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/ruby.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/r.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/rust.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/julia.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/sbt.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/selenium.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/smallstep-cli.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/terraform.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/packer.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/vcpkg.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/dpkg-config.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/mongodb.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/android.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/yq.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/pypy.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/python.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/graalvm.sh"
      ],
      "environment_vars": [
        "HELPER_SCRIPTS\u003d{{user `helper_script_folder`}}",
        "INSTALLER_SCRIPT_FOLDER\u003d{{user `installer_script_folder`}}",
        "DEBIAN_FRONTEND\u003dnoninteractive"
      ],
      "execute_command": "sudo sh -c \u0027{{ .Vars }} {{ .Path }}\u0027"
    },
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "scripts": [
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/Install-Toolset.ps1",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/Configure-Toolset.ps1"
      ],
      "environment_vars": [
        "HELPER_SCRIPTS\u003d{{user `helper_script_folder`}}",
        "INSTALLER_SCRIPT_FOLDER\u003d{{user `installer_script_folder`}}"
      ],
      "execute_command": "sudo sh -c \u0027{{ .Vars }} pwsh -f {{ .Path }}\u0027"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to add some items inside the `provisioners` list, but only inside the second index list called `scripts`, so in this case the `scripts` object. Ideally doing this all in PowerShell (I am using PowerShell 7 latest).

### What I have tried

Doing some Googling around, it was suggested that I convert the JSON to a PowerShell Object, and then attempt to add to that instead:

```
$JsonFile = "build.json"
$JsonObject = $(Get-Content $JsonFile -Raw)
$SystemObject=$($JsonObject | ConvertFrom-Json)
$OldScriptsJson = $SystemObject.provisioners[1].scripts | ConvertTo-Json
```

Which gives me the old JSON which I want to add to:

```
[
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/azcopy.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/azure-cli.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/azure-devops-cli.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/basic.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/bicep.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/aliyun-cli.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/apache.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/aws.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/clang.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/swift.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/cmake.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/codeql-bundle.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/containers.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/dotnetcore-sdk.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/erlang.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/firefox.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/gcc.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/gfortran.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/git.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/github-cli.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/google-chrome.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/google-cloud-sdk.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/haskell.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/heroku.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/hhvm.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/java-tools.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/kubernetes-tools.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/oc.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/leiningen.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/miniconda.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/mono.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/kotlin.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/mysql.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/mssql-cmd-tools.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/sqlpackage.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/nginx.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/nvm.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/nodejs.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/bazel.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/oras-cli.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/phantomjs.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/php.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/postgresql.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/pulumi.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/ruby.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/r.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/rust.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/julia.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/sbt.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/selenium.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/smallstep-cli.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/terraform.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/packer.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/vcpkg.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/dpkg-config.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/mongodb.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/android.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/yq.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/pypy.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/python.sh",
  "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/graalvm.sh"
]
```

## What I want to do

I basically want to add the following JSON to the old JSON

```json
[
    "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/colordiff.sh",
    "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/kubelogin.sh",
    "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/kubeval.sh",
    "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/kubeaudit.sh",
    "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/smallstep-cli.sh"
  ]
```

So the final product of all of this can be saved back to the original JSON:

```json
{
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "azure-arm"
    }
  ],
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "scripts": [
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/docker-compose.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/docker-moby.sh"
      ],
      "environment_vars": [
        "HELPER_SCRIPTS\u003d{{user `helper_script_folder`}}",
        "INSTALLER_SCRIPT_FOLDER\u003d{{user `installer_script_folder`}}",
        "DOCKERHUB_LOGIN\u003d{{user `dockerhub_login`}}",
        "DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD\u003d{{user `dockerhub_password`}}"
      ],
      "execute_command": "sudo sh -c \u0027{{ .Vars }} {{ .Path }}\u0027"
    },
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "scripts": [
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/azcopy.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/azure-cli.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/azure-devops-cli.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/basic.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/bicep.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/aliyun-cli.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/apache.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/aws.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/clang.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/swift.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/cmake.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/codeql-bundle.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/containers.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/dotnetcore-sdk.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/erlang.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/firefox.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/gcc.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/gfortran.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/git.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/github-cli.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/google-chrome.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/google-cloud-sdk.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/haskell.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/heroku.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/hhvm.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/java-tools.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/kubernetes-tools.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/oc.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/leiningen.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/miniconda.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/mono.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/kotlin.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/mysql.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/mssql-cmd-tools.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/sqlpackage.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/nginx.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/nvm.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/nodejs.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/bazel.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/oras-cli.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/phantomjs.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/php.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/postgresql.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/pulumi.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/ruby.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/r.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/rust.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/julia.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/sbt.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/selenium.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/smallstep-cli.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/terraform.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/packer.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/vcpkg.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/dpkg-config.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/mongodb.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/android.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/yq.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/pypy.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/python.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/graalvm.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/colordiff.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/kubelogin.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/kubeval.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/kubeaudit.sh",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/smallstep-cli.sh"
      ],
      "environment_vars": [
        "HELPER_SCRIPTS\u003d{{user `helper_script_folder`}}",
        "INSTALLER_SCRIPT_FOLDER\u003d{{user `installer_script_folder`}}",
        "DEBIAN_FRONTEND\u003dnoninteractive"
      ],
      "execute_command": "sudo sh -c \u0027{{ .Vars }} {{ .Path }}\u0027"
    },
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "scripts": [
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/Install-Toolset.ps1",
        "{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/Configure-Toolset.ps1"
      ],
      "environment_vars": [
        "HELPER_SCRIPTS\u003d{{user `helper_script_folder`}}",
        "INSTALLER_SCRIPT_FOLDER\u003d{{user `installer_script_folder`}}"
      ],
      "execute_command": "sudo sh -c \u0027{{ .Vars }} pwsh -f {{ .Path }}\u0027"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I go about that using PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```sh
$json = Get-Content 'Build.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

# Define an array of strings to add.
$scriptsToAdd = @(
    '{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/colordiff.sh'
    '{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/kubelogin.sh'
    '{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/kubeval.sh'
    '{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/kubeaudit.sh'
    '{{template_dir}}/scripts/installers/smallstep-cli.sh'
)
# Alternatively read these from a JSON file as well:
# $scriptsToAdd = Get-Content 'ScriptsToAdd.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

# Append the $scriptsToAdd array to the scripts array of the JSON
$json.provisioners[1].scripts += $scriptsToAdd

# Make sure to specify a large enough argument for -Depth, which defaults to 2.
# Otherwise objects that are nested deeper will be truncated.
$json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | Set-Content 'BuildNew.json'
```

As for what you have tried:

> ```
> $OldScriptsJson = $SystemObject.provisioners[1].scripts | ConvertTo-Json
> ```

You just converted part of the original JSON *object* back to a JSON *string*. When working with JSON, you should always operate on the object and only as a final step, convert back to the serialized JSON, which can be a  string or a file.

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you.  You do not want to know how long I was stuck on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$SystemObject = get-content build.json | convertfrom-json

# load changes into another object
$addobject = get-content add.json | convertfrom-json

# add 2 arrays together (+= kills puppies in bulk)
$SystemObject.provisioners[1].scripts += $addobject

# save, watch out for default depth of 2, the latest ps 7 gives a warning 
# "WARNING: Resulting JSON is truncated as serialization has exceeded the set depth
# of 2."
$SystemObject | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3 | set-content build2.json
```

Comment: Nice! We almost got the same solution. Note that `ConvertFrom-Json` may behave strangely when passing multiple strings (lines) as input, so it is [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71053689/7571258) to always pass `-Raw` to `Get-Content` to pass a single (possibly multiline) string to `ConvertFrom-Json`.